# PowerShell error: "Could not find member" only when executed in if condition

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Simple script to check how many updates are installed on remote computer:

```
$computername = "remotePC"
$updatesession =  [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$computer))
$updatesearcher = $updatesession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$updatesearcher.gettotalhistorycount()
```

This script runs fine for me. However, if I use the last line as an if statement condition like:

```
if($updatesearcher.gettotalhistorycount() = 0){ Write-Verbose "no update entries found"}
```

I get a `MissingMemberException`:

> "Error while invoking gettotalhistorycount. Could not find member."

I'm not sure why it would do anything differently inside the if statement. If I just have the if condition print the members of `$updatesearcher`:

```
if( write-host $($updatesearcher | gm )){}
```

It lists `gettotalhistorycount()`, but why not when I try to execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to *assign* `0` to that method. Instead, you wan't to *compare* it using `-eq`:

```
if($updatesearcher.gettotalhistorycount() -eq 0){ Write-Verbose "no update entries found"}
```